# Measure of a closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $F$ is a non-empty closed bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$ and that $S = [a,b]$ such that $S$ is the smallest closed interval containing $F$. Then, show that $S \setminus F \subset (a,b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we actually need to show is that $a,b \in F$.

Let's start with $a$. Assume towards contradiction that $a\notin F$. $F$ is closed and thus there's an interval $I = (a-\epsilon ,a+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $I\cap F = \emptyset$ (because in that case $F^c$ is open), therefore we get that $F$ is contained in $S' = [a+\epsilon , b]$ which yields contradiction that $S$ is the smallest such interval.

You could use the same method for $b$.